# Как сервер mysql хранит таблицы на жестком диске?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет. Вопрос по `mysql`. Как сервер `mysql` хранит таблицы на жестком диске? Слышал, что хранит построчно, но может и хранить по столбцам. Как достается что-то из таблицы? Тоже построчно или как-то по-другому? Хочу глубже понимать, как все это работает, чтобы стало ясно, как проходит оптимизация.

Comment: Хранить по столбам было бы дико не эффективно. каждый столбец лежит например в своем блоке диска. Дают простейший запрос `select * from table where id=1`. И тут нам пришлось бы читать с диска столько блоков, сколько у нас столбцов... Поэтому запись всегда лежит целиком. Как именно - зависит от engine. А для понимания оптимизации я бы рекомендовал в первую очередь изучить принципы индексации.

Comment: если мне нужен только, например, столбец, то не эффективно в строках хранить. потому что, чтобы этот столбец получить, придется его из каждой строки выдергивать. то есть, придется загружать ВСЮ строку и дергать кусок. лишняя память расходуется

Answer (score 1):

Вне зависимости от `storage engine` создаётся структура `frm`, содержащая описание структуры таблицы. Описание структуры есть в документации [`internals`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html).

Затем каждый `storage engine` может использовать свой подход к хранению данных. Сам `Mysql` это никак не регламентирует.

Например, `memory` или `blackhole` вообще ничего не хранят на диске. `csv` пишет данные простым `plain text` и перекодирует из/в внутренний mysql формат строк при обращении.

Что `mysql` отдаёт на откуп конкретным `storage engine` можно посмотреть в `internals`-документации в разделе [`Writing a Custom Storage Engine`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/custom-engine.html). Здесь более поподробнее описана работа с подключаемыми хранилищами. То есть сам `Mysql` абстрагируется от всего, что касается формата хранения данных на диске и как эти данные читать-писать. Но сам по себе `storage engine api` предполагает работу именно со строками во внутреннем бинарном представлении `mysql`. Кстати, там же в качестве примеров цитируют реализации других `storage engine`, например `insert` дополнен кодом из `myisam`, `update` и `delete` - из `csv`

Для [`myisam`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/myisam.html) и [`innodb`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb.html) там же в `internals` отведено по отдельному разделу. Иметь перед глазами исходник этих `storage engine` по время чтения, похоже, обязательно, описано как-то очень поверхностно. Начните лучше с раздела написания своего `storage engine`.

PS: дальше подсказать ничего не могу, не залезал. Но пусть будет хоть направление дальнейших изысканий.